# How to subtract every nth value in a column from every (n-x)th value?

Tags: r

In an R dataframe column I have a series of numbers representing timepoints. The event I am measuring lasts for six time points, so every 6th number is the onset of a new event. This means that the duration of the first event is the 6th number minus the 1st number; the duration of the second event is the 11th number minus the 6th number; etc. For instance:

1. 0
2. 117
3. 313
4. 366
5. 484
6. 761
7. 878
8. 1073
9. 1127
10. 1245
11. 1463

Event durations: (761 - 0 = 761); (1463 - 761 = 702)

How can I write a simple piece of code that will output the event durations regardless of how many events are recorded, i.e. regardless of how many values are in the column?

Comment: What should happen with the numbers in between?

Comment: For this calculation they aren't necessary, but I will do similar calculations on those numbers to measure other intervals of time during the main event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator `%%` to pick out the indices which are 1 modulo 5 (i.e. 1, 6, 11, 16, 21 etc) from an integer sequence the same length as your vector, then find the `diff` of that subset.

```r
diff(vec[seq_along(vec) %% 5 == 1])
#> [1] 761 702
```

**Data**

```r
vec <- c(0L, 117L, 313L, 366L, 484L, 761L, 878L, 1073L, 1127L, 1245L, 1463L)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `seq` to get the index and apply `diff`

```
diff(vec[seq(1, length(vec), by = 5)])
#[1] 761 702
```

#### data

```
vec <- c(0L, 117L, 313L, 366L, 484L, 761L, 878L, 1073L, 1127L, 1245L, 1463L)
```